# Find number of elements in the required set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> Consider 3 sets A, B,C such that A contains all the 3 digit numbers that are multiples of 4, B contains 3 digit numbers that are even and multiples of 3, and C contains 3 digit numbers that are multiples of 5. Find number of elements in $(A\cup B\cup C )$

Individually, A, B, C contain 225,150,180 elements respectively

I am having trouble in removing the repeated elements. Had it been 2 sets, the process was fairly straight forward, ie. finding common multiples of both sets and subtracting from total elements. But having 3 sets complicates things, and while might eventually figure it out by manual calculations, I want to know if there is a more efficient way of solving.

Comment: $C$ has $180$ elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use the principle of inclusion and exclusion:  $$|A\cup B\cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$

$A\cap B$ is a set of all 3 digit number that are divisible by $12$ and so on...